# Windows report "Unknown publisher" of signed application

Tags: windows, digital-certificate

Windows 10 started reporting my application as "Unknown publisher" when I try to run it after a download.

[image]

However, after accepting the installation, it recognizes my company as a publisher:

[image]

The application is signed with a certificate from Comodo:

[image]

It is a very unpleasant situation. How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting with January 1st, 2016 [Microsoft is implementing a mandatory update of the Digital Signature system](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32288.windows-enforcement-of-authenticode-code-signing-and-timestamping.aspx) from SHA-1 to SHA-2 in order to deal with the decreasing security of the SHA-1 digital signatures.

All applications signed with SHA-1 certificates will still be accepted until January 1st, 2017. The UAC prompt will still show the correct vendor information but the browser, i.e. Internet Explorer, will warn the users about an invalid signature. Also, the Windows SmartScreen will not recognize the SHA-1 signature and try to prevent the users from running it.